# How to configure AngularFireAuthModule and/or AngularFireAuth to point to auth emulator

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire, firebase-cli

I believe the auth emulator was released near the end of Oct. 2020. [auth emulator feature reqeust](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1677)
I'm trying to configure my locally served angular app to use the auth emulator by having angular/fire/auth make calls to localhost:9099. Is that possible yet? Or is the angular/fire team currently working on this?

My firebase config parameter in environment is:

```
firebase: {
    host: 'localhost:5000',
    ssl: false,
    apiKey: '<redacted>',
    authDomain: 'localhost:9099',
    databaseURL: '',
    projectId: '<redacted>',
    storageBucket: '',
    messagingSenderId: ''
  }
```

I placed the auth emulator port localhost:9099 in authDomain but that doesn't do the trick.

I pass the firebase object to angularfire in the import section of my app.module.ts file AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase);

To use the functions emulator I imported ORIGIN from the angular/fire/functions package and have that up and running. [doc here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md#cloud-functions-emulator). I also saw SETTINGS import for use to point the Firesore to the emulator. I can't find anything in the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md#5-getting-started-with-firebase-authentication) on how to point the auth calls to the auth emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think it's not the best place, this worked for me inside my service constructor:

```
constructor(private _angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  this._angularFireAuth.useEmulator('http://localhost:9099');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/emulators/emulators.md) can provide one best praticte like than constructor implementation. I am using in my project and worked perfectly