# AngularFireAuth emulator login is lost on page reload

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, angularfire

My Angular project successfully uses the `AngularFireAuth` injectable from [@angular/fire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire) to connect to a local Firebase authentication emulator. I used these sources as references for my implementation:

- Firebase Docs: [Instrument your app to talk to the Authentication emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth?hl=en#android_ios_and_web_sdks)
- StackOverflow: [How to configure AngularFireAuthModule and/or AngularFireAuth to point to auth emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656725/how-to-configure-angularfireauthmodule-and-or-angularfireauth-to-point-to-auth-e)

However, as soon as I reload the page the login state is lost and I have to log in again.

First I tried setting the persistence like this, in an Angular component constructor:

```js
constructor( private _fireauth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this._fireAuth.useEmulator(`http://${location.hostname}:9099/`);
    this._fireauth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
}
```

which made no difference. Then I noticed in the browser network console that apparently the firebase library does find the locally stored session after pageload but initially attempts to contact google servers to verify it, which of course fails, because it's a local emulator session:

[image]

This seemed to make sense because `_fireAuth.useEmulator()` is only called in the component constructor. Other parts of the app such as the `AngularFireAuthGuard` probably try accessing the authentication status way earlier than that. A few attempts to call `useEmulator()` before any other part of the app might attempt to access the authentication status failed:

- `Attempt1:` Calling `useEmulator()` in an `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` aka service constructor
- `Attempt2:` Providing an `APP_INITIALIZER` which executes code before the application is even bootstrapped:

```js
export function initializeApp1(afa: AngularFireAuth): any {
  return () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      afa.useEmulator(`http://${location.hostname}:9099/`);
      setTimeout(() => resolve(), 5000);
    });
  };
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
     AngularFireAuth,
     {
       provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
       useFactory: initializeApp1,
       deps: [AngularFireAuth],
       multi: true
     }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

- `Attempt3:` Providing the `USE_EMULATOR` Injectable which [seems to be implemented](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts#L70) in the `AngularFireAuth` constructor:

```
  providers: [
     {
       provide: USE_EMULATOR,
       useValue: [location.hostname, 9099]
     },
  ]
```

I thought especially `Attempt3` would set the emulator mode as early as possible because how much earlier could it be set than in the constructor? The Injectable seem to work, as the browser console prints the usual warning message on pageload: `auth.esm.js:133 WARNING: You are using the Auth Emulator, which is intended for local testing only.  Do not use with production credentials.`. However, the request to `googleapis.com` is still fired every time a stored session in the local indexedDB is detected on pageload and I'm logged out afterwards. Also worth noting: In `Attempt2` I use a 5 second timeout to slow down the app initialization noticeably and the request to `googleapis.com` is fired instantly after pageload, way before Angular has finished initializing.

At this point I don't know what to try anymore. `@angular/fire` [is obviously build upon the basic Firebase JavaScript library](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts#L83), so I might have to set emulator mode even earlier, but maybe I'm walking in the completely wrong direction here?

================================================================

[EDIT:] It seems that combining `Attempt 2` with `Attempt 3` works, as long as the `initializeApp1()` method uses a `setTimout()` of at least approx. 100ms. When I remove the timeout or set it to something as low as 10ms the login ist lost. Any timeout longer than 100ms works too. At this point it looks very much like a race condition?

Working example:

```js
export function initializeApp1(afa: AngularFireAuth): any {
  return () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      afa.useEmulator(`http://${location.hostname}:9099/`);
      setTimeout(() => resolve(), 100); // delay Angular initialization by 100ms
    });
  };
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
     // Provide the AngularFireAuth constructor with the emulator parameters
     {
       provide: USE_EMULATOR, 
       useValue: [location.hostname, 9099]
     },
     // Delay the app initialization process by 100ms
     {
       provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
       useFactory: initializeApp1,
       // for some reason this dependency is necessary for this solution to work.
       // Maybe in order to trigger the constructor *before* waiting 100ms?
       deps: [AngularFireAuth],  
       multi: true
     }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I also noticed [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts#L122) in the `AngularFireAuth` source code. So far I don't really understand what's happening, but maybe the issue is related:

> // HACK, as we're exporting auth.Auth, rather than auth, developers importing firebase.auth (e.g, `import { auth } from 'firebase/app'`) are getting an undefined auth object unexpectedly as we're completely lazy. Let's eagerly load the Auth SDK here. There could potentially be race conditions still... but this greatly decreases the odds while we reevaluate the API.

Comment: Struggling with the same issue. The auth emulator is fairly new, and it may be a bug/missing feature that needs to be corrected in one of the libs.

Comment: I just added a few new insights. It looks like a race condition in the constructor of the `AngularFireAuth` injectable.

Comment: I also found that comment, but after debugging a little more I'm more uncertain.

Comment: For the time being I'll use the combined solution of `Attempt 2` and `Attempt 3` with a 100ms timeout. I also added an `!environment.production` condition. As long as the race condition has to be dealt with only in a development environment and as long as I have this workaround I won't put any more time into this.

Comment: I don't use Emulator, but I have had a similar problem, I have solved it in Google API Console - Restrict and rename API key, adding in API Restriction section among other Token Service APIs, and it works for me.

Comment: It is actually a bug https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4110

Comment: I managed to get around it by cleaning up my dependencies so that firestore was initialized after auth. I found I had a dependency to firestore in my custom auth service.

Comment: This no longer seems to work.  I'm using Angular 12.2.4, Firebase 8.9.1 and ngx-auth-firebaseui. Using attempt 2 & 3 still causes the login to be lost. For me I was also losing the login anytime I recompiled my app, which does not happen when turning of the emulators.

Using ng serve --hmr worked for me to retain the login when recompiling, but the refresh issue still exists.  Not sure if this has something to do wth ngx-auth-firebaseui but there are no mention of any issues with the emulators on their github site.

Answer (score 0):

I've tweaked the initialize app function in my code, to use rxjs instead of promises.

```js
export const initializeApp = (angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth): (() => Observable<boolean>) => {
    if (!environment.firebaseConfig.useEmulator) {
        return () => of(true);
    } else {
        return () => of(true).pipe(
            delay(100),
            tap(_ => {
                angularFireAuth.useEmulator('http://localhost:9099/');
            })
        );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me -

Add this to the top of *app.module.ts* (before `@NgModule`) -

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/functions';

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'myApp');
if (environment.useEmulators) {
  app.auth().useEmulator('http://localhost:9099');
  app.firestore().useEmulator('localhost', 8080);
  app.functions().useEmulator('localhost', 5001);
}
```

And then further down in your *imports* section:

```
  imports: [
    ...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'myApp'),
    ...
  ],
```

I'm guessing this method "grabs" the Auth service earlier than AngularFire. But as you mentioned, the authentication emulator is quite new, hopefully in one of the next releases it will be fixed. Based on [this github post](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4110#issuecomment-747540037).

Comment: I followed your steps, which seems to be similar to https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4110. However, my auth still seems to be hitting the cloud.  I am using Angular 9.1.13, Firebase 8.9.1 and AngularFire 6.1.5.